# Pulseaudio on root usermode

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I need to enable sound on root user mode, I am on Ubuntu 12.04 when I login as root I can see the volume control is disabled, I searched and found that pulse audio wont work on root user mode, but I also found that [System-Wide Daemon](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/), so just applied this for root as shown below.

```
addgroup --system pulse
adduser --system --ingroup pulse --home /var/run/pulse pulse
addgroup --system pulse-access

# Some distributions restrict access to the sound devices to a group audio
adduser pulse audio

# Add a user to the pulse-access group
adduser root pulse-access
```

But while reboot still the volume control is disabled. What could be the issue, how can enable sound on root mode.

Basically what I want to do is using [libao](https://www.xiph.org/ao/) play some audio in root usermode, but when running the program I am getting the error like

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it by running,

`pulseaudio -D` as root on each start up.

Comment: how to do it? I'm new to ubuntu and find this a bit confusing. Do i add sudo pulseaudio -D to /etc/rc.local file?

Comment: or do you mean when the machine start's up I have to type sudo pulseaudio -D in the terminal?

Comment: Yes you can create a startup script put the command inside it, so every time when system boot the command will execute

Comment: Now I get the error `PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Access denied`

Comment: May be you have to run the command using `sudo`